# Disable Binary Logs in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, log, mysql-8.0

How can I disable binary logging on MySQL 8.0?

I am needing to import a large MySQLDump file, and don't want to fill the Binary logs with many GB of data. In the past I would have set `log_bin=0` in the `my.cnf` and restarted the database.

But with MySQL 8.0 I have tried various settings, but everytime I log onto the database, and run:

`SELECT @@global.log_bin;`

and it keeps returning `1`

I have tried:

```
log_bin = 0
log_bin = OFF
#log_bin = 1
```

Is it possible to disable to the binary logs?

Comment: Those were in the `[mysqld]` section?

Comment: That's right. Normally it has `log_bin=filename`. So I changed it to (one of) the above and restarted the database. Then tried the next one etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `log_bin_basename` is where the name goes (since early in 5.6).  And `log_bin` has _always_ been ON/OFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL 8.0 Reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html), section 5.4.4:

> The following discussion describes some of the server options and variables that affect the operation of binary logging. For a complete list, see Section 17.1.6.4, “Binary Logging Options and Variables”.
>
> Binary logging is enabled by default (the log_bin system variable is set to ON). The exception is if you use mysqld to initialize the data directory manually by invoking it with the --initialize or --initialize-insecure option, when binary logging is disabled by default, but can be enabled by specifying the --log-bin option.
>
> To disable binary logging, you can specify the --skip-log-bin or --disable-log-bin option at startup. If either of these options is specified and --log-bin is also specified, the option specified later takes precedence.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to specifying the corresponding command line argument, you can also add an option to `my.cnf`:

1. Edit `my.cnf` and add `skip-log-bin` in the `[mysqld]` section.
2. Restart `mysqld`
3. Enjoy your lack of binlogs

Note that this will remain in effect until you remove the option from the configuration file.

Comment: This is correct. To do it via the config file, then add skip-log-bin/skip_log_bin.

Comment: This appears to have worked for me.  I used the syntax "skip-log-bin = true" as it looks like that file is name=value pairs.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. I have a pretty new LAMP stack setup and am testing things out. Binary logging has been ON for a couple of weeks as I configure things. Is there any harm to deleting the files? In Unbuntu 20.04 these are stored in /var/lib/mysql/binlog.00000N. Just don't want to waste space unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

There is some conflicting info floating around. Apparently, MySQL 8.0+ enables binary logs by default so a lot of server admins are discovering this in the middle of the night due to crashed servers!

Generally speaking MySQL uses dashes `-` for inline command flags, and uses underscores `_` for permanent config option names... this is common for many apps, actually. However, for whatever reason this is becoming less true, and various formats are now acceptable (more below)...

If you want to disable binary logs for your [current session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) only, then use either:

- `--disable-log-bin`
- `--skip-log-bin`

However if you want a permanent solution, edit your `my.cnf` configuration file and add either:

- `disable-log-bin`
- `skip-log-bin`
- `disable_log_bin`
- `skip_log_bin`

I have tested all of these variations successfully in our [SlickStack boilerplate](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/mysql/my-cnf.txt). (Whichever one you choose is fine, just be sure not to include multiple versions.)

Note that the syntax shared by OP does NOT work: `log_bin = OFF`

You may be wondering why MySQL has made things so complicated, but answering that is above my pay grade and I'd venture to guess, they just want to confuse us as much as possible ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use set-environment command:

```
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-log-bin=1"
```

Next, reload configuration files and restarted the server using the
following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysqld
```

Next check the value of log_bin global variable:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('log_bin');
+---------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+---------------+----------------+
| log_bin       | OFF            |
+---------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did not work for me with Ubuntu 20.04 and MySQL 8.0.20

Answer (score 1):

Some additional information that might help windows users in particular.

TLDR Summary - *Check you have the correct config file, add one of the disable/skip options and comment out/remove any reference to setting a bin log filename.*

The service entry had a none standard defaults file specified, in my case

> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe"
> --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini

Which did not appear on the mist of options when I ran `mysql.exe --help`

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
> C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL
> Server 8.0\my.cnf

I tried all of these

- disable-log-bin
- skip-log-bin
- disable_log_bin
- skip_log_bin

And none worked, I knew I was restarting the correct service because if I stopped it I could not connect. Turns out I had a filename specified

```
log-bin="hostname-bin"
```

Commenting that out means the config options like `disable-log-bin` now work.

Answer (score 1):

Open file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and add 1 line `skip-log-bin = true` after [mysqld]

ie.

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin = true
```

save the file

restart mysql service with `sudo service mysql restart`.

To confirm it. Login to mysql using `mysql -u <user> -p<passowrd>` and run this command `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('log_bin');`

```
+---------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+---------------+----------------+
| log_bin       | OFF            |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Hope this help

Comment: This just seems to repeat the existing answers.